# How to find point estimator for $\lambda$ in Poisson distribution?

Tags: estimation, poisson-distribution, point-estimation

Suppose we have a random sample $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ from a Poisson distribution $Poi(\lambda)$.

How to find a point estimator of $\lambda$, and compute the mean and variance of the estimator.

Actually, I am confused that how to find $\lambda$. It is because I think that the mean and variance is the $\lambda$. Is it correct?

So, can anyone tell me how to find $\lambda$? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

"A" point estimator doesn't have to be the "best" point estimator that takes into account all the information. So you can just take the mean of the sample, this is a point estimator of $\lambda$.

Comment: ok, thank you so much

Comment: Is that the mean and variance of Poisson distribution is the point estimator now? I am not sure that I am correct or not. I just know that the mean and variance of Poisson distribution is $\lambda$.

Comment: An "estimator" is a rule for estimating a parameter ($\lambda$) from a given sample, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator.

Comment: I calculate that the value of mean and variance of the estimator are $\lambda$, is it correct?

Comment: The variance should decrease with sample size, so that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Oh, sorry, there is a mistake, the variance should be $\frac{\lambda}{n}$, is it correct now?

Comment: You could make this into a separate question, where you show your calculation.